# How to capture the output of the strings command?

Tags: shell, command-line, output

How do I capture the output of the strings command into a `.txt` file from the command line?

Answer (score 2):

You use redirection:

```
strings file_name > output_name.txt
```

`strings` writes to stdout (and not to stderr as some programs do), so you don't have to do anything special.